# coloring a cube with six different colors

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

a cube of length "a", width "b" and depth "c" where "a" is not equal to "b","b" is not equal to "c" and "c" is not equal to "a" . How many different ways are there to color the faces with six different colors?

Comment: Hint: There are four symmetries: the identity, and a $180^\circ$ rotation around any of the three axes.

Comment: explain please.

Comment: Those are the things you could do to a cuboid like that that don't change its shape. ("Identity" is "doing nothing," which trivially doesn't change the shape.)

Comment: how could you found the symmetries ?

Comment: Experimenting with anything cuboid-shaped (like a book or a phone) gives it to you pretty clearly

Comment: But,  I found three symmetries . please explain how you get four.

Comment: I also counted the identity ("doing nothing")

Comment: what are the four symmetries you have found?

Comment: There are three pairs of opposite faces. For each pair, rotate 180 degrees around the line through the midpoints of those faces. That gives you three. The identity is the fourth.

Comment: i don't understand the fourth symmetry  ("identity") . what that means?

Comment: The identity transformation means leaving the cube as it is.

Comment: i get it . thanks

Comment: and the answer will be 180

Comment: A symmetry is something you do to an object that doesn't change its chape. Those rotations don't change the shape, so they're symmetries. Doing nothing doesn't change the shape either, so it's a symmetry. _Every_ object has the identity as one of its symmetries.

Comment: 180 is correct, I believe.

Comment: @Tushar You should explain your reasoning in the question itself rather than the comments, where it might be missed.

Answer (score 1):

Choose two of the six colors for the largest faces.  Orient the rectangular prism so that one of these faces is on the bottom.  Notice that it does not matter which of the selected colors is on the bottom since the two selected colors will still be opposite each other.

Choose two of the four remaining colors for the next largest faces.  Orient the rectangular prism so that one of these faces is facing you.  Notice that it does not matter which which of the selected colors is facing you since the two selected colors will still be opposite each other and contiguous with both the top and bottom faces.

For the given orientation of the rectangular prism, choose which of the two remaining colors is on the left.  The remaining color is then placed on the right.  Notice that it does matter which color we place on the left.  If we orient the rectangular prism so that the color on the right is facing left without changing the bottom face, then the side facing you is rotated so that it faces away from you.

Hence, there are 
$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} \cdot 2!$$
distinguishable ways of painting the rectangular prism.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I realized that I was thinking about a related problem, namely a cube in which each face is painted a different color.  However, in this problem, the faces of the rectangular prism are different sizes. I replaced my (evidently cryptic) hint with an answer.